# TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x

soy nueva en python y estoy un poco perdida con los errores que me tira el log del cloud en donde estoy programando. Este es el codigo que previamente pase por un idle online, ya que me daba problemas de identación.
Me han pedido que tome unos datos de json y los analice por python, devolviendo una lista de alertas de la forma `{"alerts": ["temperature", "humidity"]}`.Esta es la structura de los datos de entrada, un diccionario, los cuales, los paso como argumento desde una opcion que hay en la nube donde estoy programando:

```
{
  "ambiente": "bathroom-main",
  "values": {                
    "co2": 400,
    "temperature": 22,
    "humidity": 70,
    "sound": 30,
    "illumination": 150
  }
}
```

Me han dado la tabla de valores posibles, pero hice primero para el caso que muestro arriba (Item "values" es un diccionario interno).Mi codigo es este, use la clase dict para tomar los datos del diccionario:

```
import sys

def main(dict):
    
    if dict["ambiente"] == "bathroom-main":
        alert = []
        if dict.values["co2"] >= 500:
            alert.append("co2")
        if dict.values["temperature"] < 22 and dict.values["temperature"] > 25:
            alert.append("temperature")
        if dict.values.get("humidity") < 60 and dict.values.get("humidity") > 75:
            alert.append("humidity")
        if dict.values.get("sound") < 20 and dict.values.get("sound") > 35:
            alert.append("sound")
        if dict.values.get("illumination") < 100 and dict.values.get("illumination") > 200:
            alert.append("illumination")
        return {"alertas": alert}
```

Errores que salen en el log y no entiendo (linea 65 no existe en mi codigo):

```
[
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780607Z    stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):",
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780672Z    stderr: File \"exec__.py\", line 65, in <module>",
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780683Z    stderr: res = main(payload)",
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780690Z    stderr: File \"/action/1/bin/main__.py\", line 16, in main",
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780697Z    stderr: if dict.values[\"co2\"] >= 500:",
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780704Z    stderr: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable",
  "2021-11-30T19:10:21.780710Z    stderr: "
]
```

Comment: `dict` es una palabra reservada!!! No puedes usarla en este caso

Comment: como llamas a la unción `main`??? Estas mencionando que usas la clase `dict` para tomar los valores y creo que tu lógica esta mal, por eso pregunta como es que haces el llamado a `main`

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que en un video que hicieron para este ejercicio, lo ponian así. Como debería ponerlo?

Comment: Ok, gracias, ahi lo vuelvo a intentar y aviso si funcionó.

Comment: Por cierto ahora que veo bien lo que haces, esto `dict.values` está mal, aun si cambias el nombre de la variable está mal, eso se toma como un atributo del objeto `dict` y casualmente existe un método llamado `values` por lo que retorna la definición del método y eso no es un objeto suscriptable. deberías hacer `diccionario["values"]`

Comment: Probé con dict["values"]["co2] y funcionó, ahora tengo otro problema con el operador <, que me dice:   "error": "'<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'"

Comment: Eso es por que seguro algún dato sale `None` y por ende no se puede comparar con un entero

Comment: Te recomiendo evitar usar .get en un diccionario a menos que desees que se devuelva un valor especifico si la clave no està en el diccionario. Si a get no se le indica el valor a devolver si no está la clave (segundo argumento), devuelve None. Eso significa que o escribiste mal una clave, o falta uno o más items en el diccionario.

Comment: Gracias a todos, ya solucioné el problema. Me faltaba un import json y modifique el codigo, funcionó.